# How can I get WT2g and WT10g for free?

Tags: dataset, compression, search-engine, inverted-index

As I want to test some `inverted index` compression algorithms, I need some standard datasets like those I mentioned above.

Are these datasets available as a free download?

As far as I know, these datasets are distributed by the University of Glasgow and like most other `TREC` test datasets, aren't free.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://boston.lti.cs.cmu.edu/callan/Data/).

Scroll down to `Peer-to-Peer Testbed Definitions`. But I'm not sure!

Comment: I put my comment as an answer, because it was very long. Please read it and say what is your idea about writing a crawler.  And what is your idea about twitter dataset? Do you have any information about it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Notice: It is a comment for Majid’s answer. I put it as an answer,
>   because it was very long.

As it is obvious from the name of these datasets, the size of `WT2g` is 2 Gigabytes and the size of `WT10g` is 10 Gigabytes. But the dataset that you[Majid] introduced to me, was very small. At first, I have thought this dataset is a subset of main dataset. But after I have downloaded it and saw it’s contains, I found out it is only contains the URL of sites that `WT10g` is crawled from them. Moreover, for each URL, it contains the number of pages that crawled from. (I mean the count of pages that crawled form each URL, not the pages themselves)
Totally it is seems that I can’t find this datasets for free,  but I think it is possible to write a simple crawler and use the URLs that exists in the dataset which you[Majid] introduced, as crawl seeds. I think the collection that will be created with this method, will be similar to the primary one.

Comment: may I know did you get the document from the URL. would you like to share the document???

Comment: @bob90937 For some reasons, I didn’t reconstruct `WT10g` and for my evaluations I used `AP89`, instead. Nevertheless, in the last few weeks I’ve crawled a collection of ~115,000 web pages with 14 different languages. If you’d like I can share this corpus with you.

Comment: May I know the corpus is labeled with relevant ,irrelevant or ranking, score? As I would like to have a dataset which has document, query, relevancy, ...to evaluate the search engine

Comment: do you have any research paper that you used it to compare your evaluation result with the research paper result to check how will the system is?

Comment: @bob90937 Sorry, my corpus hasn't your required metadata.